# Nunjucks - find which template file causes "template render error"

Tags: node.js, templates, nunjucks

I'm rendering Nunjucks via Node+Express.

I've got a ton of views, and suddenly one of my views is throwing an error with the following stacktrace.

How do I find out which template or helper/macro the error originated from?

`"Template render error: Template render error: Template render error: Template render error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of null
    at Object._prettifyError (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/lib.js:35:11)
    at /code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:547:19
    at eval (eval at _compile (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:617:18), <anonymous>:151:12)
    at eval (eval at _compile (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:617:18), <anonymous>:57:12)
    at eval (eval at _compile (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:617:18), <anonymous>:46:11)
    at /code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:555:11
    at eval (eval at _compile (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:617:18), <anonymous>:155:12)
    at /code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:555:11
    at eval (eval at _compile (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:617:18), <anonymous>:105:12)
    at /code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:555:11
    at eval (eval at _compile (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:617:18), <anonymous>:11:11)
    at /code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:597:9
    at Template.root [as rootRenderFunc] (eval at _compile (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:617:18), <anonymous>:188:3)
    at Template.getExported (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:595:10)
    at eval (eval at _compile (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:617:18), <anonymous>:10:5)
    at Environment.getTemplate (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:263:9)
    at Template.root [as rootRenderFunc] (eval at _compile (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:617:18), <anonymous>:8:5)
    at Template.render (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:540:10)
    at eval (eval at _compile (/code/node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:617:18), <anonymous>:104:10)
    at fn (/code/node_modules/a-sync-waterfall/index.js:26:24)
    at /code/node_modules/a-sync-waterfall/index.js:66:22
    at executeSync (/code/node_modules/a-sync-waterfall/index.js:8:15)"`

Comment: Try go to `node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js:547` and add `console.log(err, _Obj3)`.

Comment: Thanks @AikonMogwai was great for finding errors in view-helpers! But if it was an error directly in a nunjuck-file it didn't say which file. I found breaking in the catch for `_proto3.render = function render(ctx, parentFrame, cb) {` and logging `this`. Which contained `path`, the filename, and `tmplStr` - how far nunjucks got into parsing before the error occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about adding console logging in `node_modules/nunjucks/src/environment.js`, as suggested by Aikon Mogwai in the comments.

1. For viewhelpers it's good to do `console.log(err, _Obj3)` at line `547` (inside a catch in `this.rootRenderFunc(this.env, context, frame, globalRuntime, function (err, res) {` )
2. For errors in `.njk` it was better to do a `console.log(this);` at `526` ( inside a catch in `_proto3.render = function render(ctx, parentFrame, cb) {` )

The logged object will contain the following useful properties

- `filename` -> absolute path to the file causing the error
- `tmplStr` -> all the contents of that file it could parse before the error
- a bunch of context objects containing, for example, all the Nunjucks globals and filters present at the time